# How to move Trello cards when Jira issues status is updated

Tags: automation, jira, webhooks, trello, zapier

We have Zapier basic account and the only zap we have seen is creating trello cards when new jira issues is created.

We also tried creating a custom zap but there is no trigger for updates. Everything is only upon creating new issues, new projects, and new users.
Our Jira account is on cloud.

We know about other premium add-ons and premium third party sources but we already have Zapier basic.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their [website](https://zapier.com/zapbook/jira/), it appears that there is now a trigger from JIRA when issues are updated.

Comment: We ended up using another 3rd party integration tool and later on stopped using Trello. I accepted the answer because as I checked there are indeed new integrations and triggers. Thanks @russellpierce